# Dynamic number of collectionview cells depending on iPhone

Tags: ios

I have a collectionview right now with rows of rectangular cells in it. The following scenario is what I would like to achieve:

A) If it's an iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S:
Display two cells in each row and fill the width with margins in between each cell.

B) if it's an iPhone 6, 6 Plus:
Display three cells in each row and fill the width with margins in between each cell.

Is this possible with Autolayout?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that it is possible using auto layout because this is the constant which you are going to return in one of the delegate method of collection view.

Comment: you can put a check on scale property of UIScreen and return the values related to that.

Comment: check iphone 6 condition... if iphone 6 then collection view width Increased via code.collection view auto adjust cell.